# Sum of visible Points in ChartJs Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

the chartjs has the option to hide datasets by clicking on the label. I want to sum up all points of the barchart, but only the visible ones. I know how to sum up all points, but don't know how to check if the dataset is Visible or not. To sum up the points I use the onComplete animation event:

```js
animation: {
    onComplete: function(animation) {
    var sqm = 0;
    this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
    dataset.data.forEach(function (points) {
        sqm = sqm + points;
         })
    })
    $("#SquareMeterSurface").val(sqm);
    }
},
```

here is how it looks like:

[image]

How can I do the sum for visible datasets only (in the graph above the blue ones are not visible)? I use ChartJs 2.8

thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution by myself. In the 'animation' variable passed to the onComplete callback is an array 'animation.chart.active' which can be looped to find the active dataset Indexes. The active array is only populated when hovering over the bars of the graph, thats why the sum of points are only displayed when hovering over the bars.

The whole code looks now like this:

```
 function success_(data) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: data,
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Square Meters done per day'
            },
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'index',
                intersect: false
            },
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            responsive: true,
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    stacked: true
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    stacked: true
                }]
            },
            animation: {
                onComplete: function(animation) {
                    //alert('onAnimationComplete');

                    if (typeof animation.chart !== 'undefined' && typeof animation.chart.active !== 'undefined') {
                        var active_datasets = new Array();
                        //loop through active dataset to get the dataset indexes 
                        //which are visible to the user
                        animation.chart.active.forEach(function(active_ds) {
                            active_datasets.push(active_ds._datasetIndex);
                        })

                        //loop through datasets to get the points for active datasets
                        var sqm = 0;
                        var i = 0;
                        this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
                            if (active_datasets.indexOf(i) != -1) {
                                dataset.data.forEach(function (points) {
                                    sqm = sqm + points;
                                })
                            }
                            i = i + 1;
                        })
                        $("#SquareMeterSurface").val(parseFloat(sqm).toFixed(1) + ' m2');
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    });
};
```

and the ajax call to  invoce a .Net Core MVC action is like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/YourController/YourActionForGraph/',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        'param1': $('#param1').val(),
        'param2': $('#param2').val()
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: success_,
    error: function (request, error) {
        alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your hint. This one helped me, so I came up with the following solution:

```
`const options = {
    radius: "100%",
    cutout: "90%",
    animation: {
      onComplete: function (animation) {
        console.log(animation.chart.getDatasetMeta(0));
      },
    },
  };`
```

You can call `getDatasetMeta(index)` on the `chart object` and you will get an object with all current data used to construct the chart. Here you find the total property with the current sum.

See: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getdatasetmeta-index